# TFTP an entire directory, problem with spaces in names

Tags: busybox, tftp

I've done a bit of digging, but I haven't discovered a working solution yet (to my surprise.)  I've been trying this:

```
# for i in `ls`; do tftp -l "$i" -p 192.168.1.100; done
```

I just want to TFTP the contents of an entire directory (without tar/zipping them up). The problem is, of course, spaces in file names break everything.  Maybe I should be using some other strategy?

Shell scripting isn't exactly my strong point...

(Extra points (not really) if there is a working recursive solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type

```
IFS=$(echo -en "\n\b")
```

before executing your loop, this will fix file name problem.

If you want to recursively tftp files use the following -

```
find . -print0 | while read -d $'\0' i
do
   tftp -l "$i" -p 192.168.1.100
done
```

Comment: Now I just have to figure out what this all means :)