# TFTP a file containing a space

Tags: tftp

On a windows 10 machine, I have installed a TFTP server (TFTPD64 by Ph. Jounin). I created two files named 'test.txt' and 'test me.txt' on this windows machine.

Then, on a linux tftp client (atftp) I used the command `get test.txt` to get my first file. This worked as expected.

However, when I try to get 'test me.txt' it doesn't work:

```
tftp> get test me.txt
tftp: error received from server <File 'test' does not exist>
tftp: aborting
```

---

```
tftp> get test\ me.txt
Overwrite local file [y/n]? y
tftp: error received from server <File 'test\' does not exist>
tftp: aborting
```

```
tftp> get 'test me.txt'
tftp: error received from server <File ''test' does not exist>
tftp: aborting
```

How can I get 'test me.txt'? Maybe with another tftp client?

Comment: Im no expert, but have you tried lutting double quotes around the filename - ie get "test me.txt"

Comment: Yes, I tried it but same problem.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TFTP an entire directory, problem with spaces in names](https://superuser.com/questions/333348/tftp-an-entire-directory-problem-with-spaces-in-names)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I solved my problem is to use SFN: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/8.3_filename